# Combining CSS Classes in CSS Modules in React

Tags: css, reactjs, react-css-modules

I am using Fontawesome icons in my react and I am using CSS modules in react. Now I want to use this Icon  so I am using the following syntax : `<i className={styles['fa-user-circle']} ></i>`
I cant use normal syntax `styles.someClassName` because of hyphens in the name of fontawesome icons and also I need to combine fas and fa-user-circle classNames . How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: have you checked this out? https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

Comment: ill check it out and let you know if it works . fingers crossed!

Comment: If you want to use multiple classnames, you can achieve it using something like: <div classNames={[styles['fa-user-circle'], styles['fas'] ].join(' ')} />

Comment: Thanks it works but how do I customize I want to change its color and so on ?

Comment: the react component of fa works! how do I customize it

Comment: yes i like to change color of the icon and also size yes i want to override but also i would like to take react component approach since its modern

Comment: You can have it's own class or styles or size as shown: <FontAwesome
        className='super-crazy-colors'
        name='rocket'
        size='2x'
        spin
        style={{ textShadow: '0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)' }}
      />

Comment: thanks it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FontAwesome React version [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react)

Implementation of it looks like

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

and your render component looks like

```
 export default (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="pointer" onClick={props.onAdd} id={props.id} />
    </div>
 )
}
```

As you can see className we can give so whatever the extra CSS you want to give you can.